# Using PHP data to place multiple markers on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am working on a web page that gets information from a MySQL database and then places multiple markers on the map based on the data. While my map integration worked properly, my code to use the PHP data stopped the map from displaying. It does not show any errors, however.

Here is the code. I am new to JavaScript but I believe the problem is in the function that has the PHP `echo` statements. I really appreciate the help.

PHP:

```
$lat = [];
$long = [];
$location = [];
$id = [];
$count = 0;
$count2 = 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name Order BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($id, $row['id']);
    $count++;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $webId = $id[$i];
    $webSearch = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='$webId'");
    $web = mysqli_fetch_array($webSearch);
    array_push($lat, $row['lat']);
    array_push($long, $row['longi']);
    array_push($location, $row['city']);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
    var count = <?php echo $count;?>;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: <?php echo $lat[$count2];?>,
                lng: <?php echo $long[$count2]; ?>
            },
            map: map,
            title: <?php echo $lat[$count2]; $count2++;?>
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?  (HTML, CSS, JavaScript from the page rendered to the browser).

Comment: what is the purpose of the two sql queries?

Answer (score 0):

I understand why the map was not displaying. It was missing the following map initialization.

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: {lat: 25.363, lng: 131.044}
          });
```

There was also an error with the PHP variable names. After that was fixed, PHP data passed flawlessly to Javascript. However, the for-loop is only printing out one marker.

Comment: I think it MIGHT be adding all the markers but at the same location due to the use ( or misuse ) of the php variable `$count2` which is initialised as `zero` and never changed. You would be far better to use PHP simply to generate the recordset and subsequent json object and leave the rest of the functionality to javascript

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand the purpose of the two sql queries - selecting 
everything from a table and then selecting everything again from the 
same table... one query should, as far as I can see, suffice.

Also, using PHP within the javascript and expecting the counter `$count2` to be anything other than either the initial value ( as here ) or the last value if it were changed would be a fallacy. As `$count2` is initially given the value `0` it retains that value as the variable is never changed anywhere but is used within the javascript code to access data from the PHP variables `$lat` and `$long` - which will always yield the same result and thus render a single marker - or multiple markers at the same location.

Perhaps consider an approach like the following where the php code runs and fetches the recordset and is converted into JSON data for the map code to process natively using only javascript.

```
/*
    Fetch the results and convert to JSON for the js code... or an empty array
    if the query fails.
*/

$sql = 'select * from `table_name` order by `id` desc';
$result = $con->query( $sql );
$json = $result ? json_encode( $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) : json_encode( array() );




<script>
    /*
        As PHP runs before the page is rendered you can print
        the javascript variable and it will be available to 
        your map handling code - `initMap`
    */
    <?php
        echo "var json={$json};";
    ?>

    function initMap(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: {lat: 25.363, lng: 131.044}
        });

        var obj,marker;
        /*
            The json data should be accessible like this - or
            by a very similar syntax.
        */
        for( var i in json ){
            obj=json[ i ];

            marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: obj.lat,
                    lng: obj.longi
                },
                map: map,
                title: obj.city
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```